# How do I connect static libs in CLion with CMake?

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

I want to use OpenGL 4.5 and freeglut in my project. I've got compiled freeglut library (include folder, .dll and .lib). Here's CMakeLists.txt I've got so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(DuperTest)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(DuperTest ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(DuperTest ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(DuperTest ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/freeglut.lib)
```

But still no luck `#include <gl.h>` and `#include <GL/freeglut.h>` still not working. What should I do?

Comment: `${${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include}` should have been  `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include`.

Comment: @Tulon sorry iwas misprint while editing post

Comment: Where is your `freeglut.h` located? Is it in `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/GL`?

Comment: yes, it's in `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/GL`

Comment: You still have an extra `}` in `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include}`. Without it, `#include <GL/freeglut.h>` should work. As for `#include <gl.h>`, shouldn't that be `#include <GL/gl.h>`?